# What is this plant with leaves over a foot long, in Pennsylvania?

Tags: identification, leaves

I found this plant growing on an overgrown hill slope full of wild plants and weeds in Pennsylvania. It looks like a Dock plant or a super large plantain leaf. I just collected a good amount of them, and want to know if they are edible. I'm hoping its medicinal qualities aid in helping the kidneys and liver, as do dandelions and plantains.

*click on picture for full size*

[image: plant growing on hill slope well overgrown in Pa.]

Comment: Looks a little like comfrey

Comment: I just looked up comfrey, the veins are wrong from the photos I saw and these leaves are very smooth and has a light sheen.

Comment: Have these plants flowered over the seasons at all?

Comment: I just came apon them but I examined the plants closely and no stalks or anything that might suggest it flowers at all.

Comment: This late in the year, and seeing the fact that it has no flower stalk and few tillers, makes me think it's a biennial.

Comment: hmm never heard of the term but am looking it up a plant called Woad looks close to it but still the veins of the plant don't quite match, (sighs) this is frustrating but interesting

Comment: also reminds me of rudbeckia/echinacea. Wonder if it's in the sunflower family

Comment: hmm some veins match but my leaves are smoother no real hair on them will try later to upload a close up of the leaves. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about Comfrey...?  Doesn't look like Italian Arum to me anyhoo.  Do you remember ANYTHING about the flowers?  Check this out...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comfrey

This is plantain and I went out to check.  Here is a link for different views of plantain, different species.  Great to know what plants to eat or not eat in the wild. Plantain is great, dandelion is super, nettles are yummy...but please take care to KNOW what it is you are eating, sometime a little is fine, a bit more is toxic.[plantain](https://www.google.com/search?q=plantain%20weed&rlz=1C1QJDB_en&espv=2&biw=1455&bih=726&tbm=isch&imgil=Lq3lEaNuAwBq0M%253A%253BPMN_iUFwHowdtM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fhappyturf.com%25252Fweeds%25252Fplantain.php&source=iu&pf=m&fir=Lq3lEaNuAwBq0M%253A%252CPMN_iUFwHowdtM%252C_&ved=0CCgQyjdqFQoTCNW0or7akMgCFRUpiAodxpkE7g&ei=dXcEVpWmDpXSoATGs5LwDg&usg=__9PSM-c7JmmIX-9G30mc6AglmKXg%3D#imgrc=Lq3lEaNuAwBq0M%3A&usg=__9PSM-c7JmmIX-9G30mc6AglmKXg%3D)

Comment: Thanks I was hoping it was just I have never seen one with leaves over a foot long. :)

Comment: This plant is sorta shaded, yes?  Their leaves will get huge to be able to catch as much sun as possible.  Grins!  But just because I think it is plantain don't eat it, make very sure.  Be careful with other plants you might pull up inadvertantly that might be toxic.  I am just going by your picture.  Knowing what to eat and what not to eat in the wild is important.  I've taken lots of wilderness survival classes and 'when in ANY doubt don't eat it!'

Comment: Nope wasn't going to unless 100 % know what it is. I was hoping though because am also looking for various plantain for a poultice, ahh well least I am learning a lot about the plants around me. :)

Comment: The plant is on hill slope I'd say perhaps half shade due to taller weeds near it but not over it that I can tell.

Comment: OH wow could this be a erythronium pagoda leaves?

Comment: This does not appear to be plantain

Comment: well I checked on this plant and found several like it in the vicinity so am watching to see if it grows a stem or flowers or what. I am surprised how long and big the leaves are still no change in color either and seems to have come through the winter with little change in appearance.

Comment: Have you seen reproductive growth yet?  Could you take a picture of the underside of the leaves?  Pull one up and show us the roots?  The flowers should solve this right away.  This is now spring and they should be showing something, yes?  So far I am voting for comfrey.  This gets lots bigger than plantain.  Never seen Italian Arum...sounds awful.

Answer (score 0):

This I believe is Italian Arum. If it has corn cob like seed cluster stalks/flowers, turns from green to orange, and you can't get rid of it, then that's it. Toxic, do not crush or ingest. I did as a kid and paid for it with burning/itching hands for hours. Washing them seemed to do nothing. I am guessing, this pic reminds me of a younger plant though. It was also very hard to I.D. this, seemed as if no one knew,Grandmas,Professionals, etc. Finally years later at a seminar about weed I.D.,I asked an extension employee and described it, this was his answer....terrible stuff....

Comment: well I went back to check the plant out again 2 days ago, still no stalk growing, as if to grow a flower or anything, just leaves. It has me stumped for sure, but I will keep checking on it to see if it developes anything.

Comment: How do I post other photos to show the update on this plant?